# Desarrollo de app ios con phonegap

Tags: ios, app, phonegap

quiero hacer una consulta sobre desarrollo móvil, quiero aclarar que no he desarrollado ninguna app para móvil.

Tengo un cliente que necesita una app para ios, no es muy compleja, sé que por lo general se utiliza swift para desarrollar en ios, pero como no tengo una pc o laptop apple he optado por trabajarla con phonegap.

Mi consulta es si hago la app con phonegap, tendría algún inconveniente al poner la app en la app store? o puedo instalar la app en tablets apple sin tener la app en la app store?

Gracias desde ya y espero su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

> pero como no tengo una pc o laptop apple he optado por trabajarla con phonegap.

Puedes [realizar el desarrollo con Phonegap](https://web.archive.org/web/20150303180446/http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac) sin tener una mac, pero eventualmente necesitarás una con Xcode para realizar la publicación en la store.

> tendría algún inconveniente al poner la app en la app store?

En teoría no, [existen apps ya publicadas](https://phonegap.com/app/) hechas con Phonegap solo tendrías que apegarte a los [lineamientos](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/) de apple para el desarrollo de apps

> puedo instalar la app en tablets apple sin tener la app en la app store?

Aquí tienes dos opciones, la ideal es usar la [Enterprise Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/), donde puedes realizar deployments privados. Otra opción (que yo no te recomendaría) es hacer un deployment manual en los dispositivos registrándolos como devices de desarrollo en la cuenta de desarrollador (solo tienes derecho a 100)

Además para crear los build necesitarías usar [phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com/).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus respuestas Kristian, me has aclarado más el panorama, investigaré mas, saludos.